# How to add a loop resultat to a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, loops

I want to add the result from the loop (what is in consol.log) to the select tag as an options.

```
function CustomeSelect(props) {

    const values = props.values;

    for (const entry of values) {
       console.log(`<option value=${entry[0]}>${entry[1]}</option>`)
    }    

    return (
        <div>
            <label for={props.for}>{props.title}</label>
            <select value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} id={props.id}>


// Here I want to add `<option value=${entry[0]}>${entry[1]}</option> - what is in console.log.
                
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `select value={props.value}` whats props.value will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through `values` property and for each item return an option tag like this

```
function CustomeSelect(props) {
    const { values } = props;

    return (<div>
        <label for={props.for}>{props.title}</label>
        <select value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} id={props.id}>

            // Here I want to add `${entry[1]} - what is in console.log.
            {Array.from(values).map(entry => {
                return <option value={entry[0]}>{entry[1]}</option>
            })}

        </select>
    </div>);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but thank you for your help.

Comment: can you update your question and provide the error which you have

Comment: "TypeError: values.map is not a function"

Comment: When you use the `CustomeSelect` component did you pass a props named `values`? In case It's provide you can force javascript to consider `values` as an array by using `Array.from` method

Comment: Now it's working! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

this way it will work,

```
function CustomeSelect(props) {

  return (
      <div>
          <label for={props.for}>{props.title}</label>
          <select onChange={props.onChange} id={props.id}>
            
            {props.values.map(
              entry => return <option key={Math.random()} value={entry[0]}>${entry[1]}</option>
            )}

          </select>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but thank you for your help.

Comment: @YerbaMate what getting wrong with error please

Answer (score 0):

You can use map method as shown below. Remember **values.map** will iterate over the array and gives individual value.

```
function CustomeSelect(props) {

const values = props.values;
// assume const values = [ "one", "two", "three" ]


return (
    <div>
        <label for={props.for}>{props.title}</label>
         <select value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} id={props.id}>
         {
           values.map((val , index) => (
             <option key={index} value={val}>{val}</option>
            ))
         }
        </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```